# Temporary macro to store another macro and then reverting back

Tags: c++, macros

I want to have more control over macros such as assertions (and some logging macros that are not directly under my control). So I decided to do something like this, expecting it to work (in case somebody is wondering, the reason it does not work is that the last `undef` of `MY_ASSERT_COPY` invalidates `MY_ASSERT` right before it).

```
#ifndef ENABLE_FULL_ERROR_ASSERTS
#define MY_ASSERT_COPY MY_ASSERT
#undef MY_ASSERT
#define MY_ASSERT
#endif

// Code for my current class, which happens to be header only

#ifndef ENABLE_FULL_ERROR_ASSERTS
#undef MY_ASSERT
#define MY_ASSERT MY_ASSERT_COPY
#undef MY_ASSERT_COPY
#endif
```

Now I know a few ways around it, one being to define another macro for assertions just for that file, which I can then turn off without affecting assertions in any other part of the program. I initially thought this was a really elegant solution (before I found out it did not compile) that will allow me to use `MY_ASSERT` everywhere and then simply turn it off for particular files.

Since the above doesn't work, is there a workaround that will allow me to selectively kill the macro without affecting the surrounding code and without defining another substitute macro like `#define MY_ASSERT_FOR_VECTORS MY_ASSERT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some compilers provide `#pragma push_macro`and `#pragma pop_macro` to save and restore macro state.

Limited portability though.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work in all situations, but maybe you could simply `undef` the macros, define them as you wish and then `undef` them again.

The next time your code uses some of these macros it should `#include` the header files where they were initially defined so it will define those macros again.

One safe option would be:

```
#ifndef ENABLE_FULL_ERROR_ASSERTS
#undef MY_ASSERT
#define MY_ASSERT ....
#endif

// Code for my current class, which happens to be header only

#ifndef ENABLE_FULL_ERROR_ASSERTS
#undef MY_ASSERT
#include "headers.h"  //etc
// line above should redefine the macros
#endif
```

Comment: "line above should redefine the macros" only if it doesn't have a header guard.  And doesn't define any template functions. Or classes.  Or anything else that would cause problems from a second inclusion.  Plus you would need to end and restart any namespace blocks around the #include.

Comment: yeah, I guess you're right! But again, as I said "This may not work in all situations"... This might be worth a look if ``push macro`` isn't available.